# Problema ao criar foreign key no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Bem eu tenho de relacionar 3 tabelas e estou a tentar criar as `foreign key` eu consigo criar só que no php tenho um `INSERT` para umas das tabelas que não efectua a inserção e acusa o seguinte o que estou fazendo errado no `Foreign key` ? Como posso resolver este problema ?

**Erro**

```
foreign key constraint fails (`sabeonde_sabeonde`.`notificacoes_visualizacao`,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_notificacao_visualizacao_notificacao` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_notificacao`) REFERENCES `notificacoes` (`id`) ON DELETE
    NO ACTION ON UPD)' in  /home/sabeonde/public_html/ajax/mostra_notificacoes.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sabeonde/public_html/ajax/mostra_notificacoes.php(41): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 {main}
```

**Notificacoes**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notificacoes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_destino_notificacao` int(11) NOT NULL,
`notificacao` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`tipo` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

**Tabela notificacoes_visualizacao**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `notificacoes_visualizacao` (
  `id_notificacao` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario_que_visualizou` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_notificacao`,`id_usuario_que_visualizou`),
  KEY `fk_notificacao_visualizacao_usuario_idx` (`id_usuario_que_visualizou`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Limitadores para a tabela `notificacoes_visualizacao`
--
ALTER TABLE `notificacoes_visualizacao`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_notificacao_visualizacao_notificacao` FOREIGN KEY (`id_notificacao`) REFERENCES `notificacoes` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_notificacao_visualizacao_usuario` FOREIGN KEY   (`id_usuario_que_visualizou`) REFERENCES `users_social` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**Codigo php de insersao**

```
    $sql = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO notificacoes_visualizacao (id_notificacao, id_usuario_que_visualizou) VALUES (:id_notificacao, :id_usuario_que_visualizou)");
    $sql->bindParam(':id_notificacao', $row_notificacoes['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sql->bindParam(':id_usuario_que_visualizou', $user_actual, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $sql->execute();
```

Comment: Se possível, adicione o código php de inserção à sua pergunta.

Comment: Já editei a pergunta e coloquei o código